# html input type file attaching more than 1 file per uploaded file

Tags: php, html, ajax, file-upload, email-attachments

I have a form that contains an input of type file that when submitted is sent to a php file using ajax and form data.

my html code is:

```
<input type="file" name = "attachments" multiple>
```

and on the php side:

```
echo count($_FILES["attachments"]);
foreach($attachments as $attached)
   query("INSERT INTO attachments (`file_id`,`message_id`,`file`)VALUES (NULL , '$message_id','$attached')");
```

The problem is that when uploading one single file the echo statement is echoing 5 even though on the html side it shows , and when inserting into the database the file is inserted as 5 blob objects.

When I use name = "attachments" (not an array) I get the following inserted into the database:

```
file_id message_id file

284     19         [BLOB - 11 B]

285     19         [BLOB - 9 B]

286     19         [BLOB - 20 B]

287     19         [BLOB - 1 B]

288     19         [BLOB - 3 B]
```

When I use name = "attachments[]" I get the following inserted 5 times:

```
file_id message_id file

289     19         [BLOB - 5 B]
```

Does anyone know how this is happening ?

Comment: First, get rid of the spaces around the `=` in your input, second try replacing `attachments` name attribute to `attachments[]`.

Comment: @JonStirling i tried it with both attachments[] and attachments and i still got the same problem

Comment: And you got rid of the spaces? What's the output from `var_dump($_FILES);` when you submit?

Comment: Adding the `[]` has actually fixed part of your problem, it's now inserting the string "Array" into your field since `$attached` is an array containing the details on the file. The next problem you have is putting the right stuff into the `file` column, which is a whole other question since you want to put the file data into it, not the metadata _about_ the file which is what the `$_FILES` superglobal contains.

Comment: @JonStirling true and `var_dump($_FILES);` is showing as u said info about the uploaded file not the file itself... how do i get the uploaded file itself and not its info ??

Comment: The uploaded file can be found in the `tmp_name` index in those arrays. Read in the file data, and INSERT that. I would suggest considering a different option though, the general pattern is to store a file path in the DB rather than the image itself. Some quick googling should provide you with more info as to why.